# What do sklearn.cross_validation scores mean?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am working on a time-series prediction problem using `GradientBoostingRegressor`, and I think I'm seeing significant overfitting, as evidenced by a significantly better RMSE for training than for prediction.  In order to examine this, I'm trying to use `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate`, but I'm having problems understanding the result.

First:  I was calculating RMSE by fitting to all my training data, then "predicting" the training data outputs using the fitted model and comparing those with the training outputs (the same ones I used for fitting).  The RMSE that I observe is the same order of magnitude the predicted values and, more important, it's in the same ballpark as the RMSE I get when I submit my predicted results to Kaggle (although the latter is lower, reflecting overfitting).

Second, I use the same training data, but apply `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` as follows:

```
cross_validate( predictor, features, targets, cv = 5, scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error" )
```

I figure the `neg_mean_squared_error` should be the square of my RMSE.  Accounting for that, I still find that the error reported by cross_validate is one or two orders of magnitude smaller than the RMSE I was calculating as described above.

In addition, when I modify my GradientBoostingRegressor `max_depth` from 3 to 2, which I would expect reduces overfitting and thus should improve the CV error, I find that the opposite is the case.

I'm keenly interested to use Cross Validation so I don't have to validate my hyperparameter choices by using up Kaggle submissions, but given what I've observed, I'm not clear that the results will be understandable or useful.

Can someone explain how I *should* be using Cross Validation to get meaningful results?

Comment: One simple clarification. Can you explain better how you do training? Once you have fitted the model do you use the same data for prediction?

Comment: Sure:   The task is, given 34 months of sales information across a number of shops and items, predict sales for the next month for each shop/item.   For training, I use months [0,33] as the features and month 34 as the target.  For the predictions, I use months [1,34] as the features and predict month 35.  Thus, I wouldn't expect to see the training RMSE to be exactly equal to the prediction's RMSE (which Kaggle calculates for me), but I'd think they'd at least be of comparable order of magnitude, but they're not.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conceptual problem here.

If you want to compute the error of a prediction you should not use the training data. As the name says these type of data are used only in training, for evaluating accuracy scores you have to use data that the model has never seen.

About cross-validation I can tell that it's an approach to find the best training/testing set. The process is as follows: you divide your data into `n` groups and you do various iterating changing the testing group you pick. If you have `n` groups you will do `n` iteration and each time the training and testing set will be different. It's more understandable in the image below.

[image: Cross Validation method]

Basically what you should do is:

- Train the model using months from 0 to 30 (for example)
- See the predictions made with months from 31 to 35 as input.

If the input has to be the same length divide feature in half (should be 17 months).

I hope I understood correctly, otherwise comment.

Comment: Federico, I *think* I understand CV, and the reason I'm using CV is to get a more realistic estimate of what the error would be when predicting "new" data.   What I didn't understand (among many other things...) is why the CV errors don't seem to be commensurable with the "self-errors".   I do understand that the "self-errors" are an over-optimistic estimate (due to overfitting) but I was hoping CV would lend *some* insight about the overfitting itself.

Comment: oooo ok now i get it